# GridLayout messing up my labels

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I'm writing simple calendar application. I have one function to draw difrrent months however somehow some of them are messed up. Here: 
[image]

As you can see May(5) and August(8) doesn't display properly. In diffrent years diffrent months are broken. Here's the function responsible for drawing these:

```
 JPanel month = new JPanel();

 month.setBackground(Color.white);
 month.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,180));
 month.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,6));
 for (int j=0; j<=6; j++)   //adding days of week labels
 {
      JLabel dayNameLabel = new JLabel(days[j]);
      dayNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Monospace", Font.ITALIC, 12));
      dayNameLabel.setOpaque(true);
      dayNameLabel.setForeground(Color.gray.darker());
      dayNameLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
      month.add(dayNameLabel );

 }
 int dayOfWeek=new GregorianCalendar(myDate.year,argMonth, 1).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
 int howMuchDays=new GregorianCalendar(myDate.year,argMonth, 1).getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

 for(int j=0;j<dayOfWeek-1;j++){   //Adding blank spaces so every day can be on it's spot
     JLabel blank = new JLabel(" ");
     month.add(blank);
 }


 for (int j = 1; j<howMuchDays+1;j++)
 {
      JLabel dayField = new JLabel(Integer.toString(j));
      dayField.setFont(new Font("Monospace", Font.BOLD, 12));
      dayField.setOpaque(true);
      dayField.setBackground(Color.white);
      if (new GregorianCalendar(myDate.year, argMonth, j).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 7)
          dayField.setForeground(Color.RED);    //make sunday red
      else
          dayField.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

      month.add(dayField );
 }


 add(month);
```

I've tried changing fonts or found some dependence but I haven't got nowhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new GridLayout(6,6)`?? This makes no sense, since you don't want a 6 by 6 grid.

Wouldn't you instead want to use `new GridLayout(0, 7)`? This stands for a grid of variable number of rows but always with 7 columns, which should be exactly what you need.